# Computing cross-correlation of different size vectors using FFT

Tags: algorithms

I've been given this exercise as homework but I'm hard-stuck on it for a few hours now.
Basically what I need to show is that cross correlation of 2 vectors of size n and m, for m <= n, can be computed in O(n*log(m)).

say |x| = n, |y| = m.
I tried computing (∗R) because its the same vector with a shift of indexes. I zero-padded both vectors to achieve a mutual length of n+m, so I could use cyclic convolution:

⊛=〖〗^(−1) (()∙())

But now I can't compute these DFTs in O(nlog(m)). I noticed DFT(x)*DFT(y) is the convolution x*y, but that's like back to square one.

Would appreciate any hint for this problem . Thanks!

Edit: 
For 2 vectors of equal sizes, I can zero-pad them then use the cyclic convultion relation from earlier -  ⊛=〖〗^(−1) (()∙()) , and achieve O(nlogn) time.
I failed to do it for n=2m without using 'big' DFTs. I tried breaking x into m-sized chunks. While I can compute the convolution for the first m indexes using 2 m-sized DFTs, I need info from the first chunk to compute the second one...

Comment: Can you solve it for the case where $m=n$?  If so, can you solve it for the case where $n=2m$, but without using a DFT of length $2m$ or $3m$ (only using smaller DFTs)?  for $n=cm$ for some integer constant $c$?  I suggest editing the question to show which of those you do know how to solve (and the solution method you came up with) and which is the first you don't know how to solve.

Comment: @D.W. Added. Also, I think I need zero-padding when using the cylic conovlution. That makes even the DFT of y a DFT of 2m length, doesn't it? Or shouldn't I use it at all?

Comment: @D.W. Ah figured it out, I think. Breaking x into m-sized chunks then computing the convolution of each chunk with y appears to work - need to add up neighboring chunks tho.

Comment: Would you like to write up a detailed answer now?

Comment: Yeah, I'll do it tomorrow or so, overflowing with work atm. Thanks for your help!